# MATLAB: evaluate a polynomial based on zeros and initial condition

Tags: matlab, polynomial-math

On MATLAB, it's possible to get the coefficients of a polynomial `p` based on its roots through

```
r = [5 6 18];
p = poly(r);
```

My problem requires that the coefficients of the polynomial satisfy f(0) = -2, however, and I don't know how to integrate this requirement into the command above. I have access to `polyval()` as well, but I'm not sure how that'd help.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is f(0)=-2 the only condition on your polynomial?

Comment: Yeah, that and that the roots be the ones in "r"

Comment: So would this be technically `5x^2 + 6x + 18`?

Comment: Can you use `polyfit`? That would be the standard Matlab way to do this, given you can't use `poly` as you have a specified point that is not a zero.

Comment: @rayryeng no it would be `(x-5)*(x-6)*(x-18)` with an additional term to make f(0)=-2.

Comment: `polyfit` wasn't in the list of "suggested functions", but I'm sure it'd be fine... how would you, though?

Comment: @David - Thanks.  Not familiar with `poly`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific case (where `f(0)` is not a root of the equation), you can simply do the following:

```
r=[5 6 18]
p=poly(r)
f0=-2
p=p*f0/polyval(p,0) %// just scaling p so that f(0)=-2
polyval(p,0) %// checking the answer
```

But in general, you can use `polyfit`

```
p2=polyfit([0 r],[-2 0 0 0],3) %// f(0)=-2 and f(r)=0 for r=5,6,18
```